# xev doesn't identify some keys, and some have incorrect mappings?

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap

My keyboard modifier map as returned by `xmodmap` is:

> ```
> shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
> lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
> control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
> mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
> mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
> mod3
> mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
> mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
> ```

When I run `xev | awk -F'\''[ )]+'\'' '\''/^KeyPress/ { a[NR+2] } NR in a { printf "%-3s %s\n", $5, $8 }'\'` to awk out just the keys' serials and names from the `xev` output soup I get no response for the `<PrintScreen>`, `<Fn>`, and the `<Return>` key on my number-pad. The raw `xev` output for these keys looks very different from the regular output and looks something like this:

- `<PrintScreen>` pressed and released

> ```
> FocusOut event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
>     mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor
>
> FocusOut event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
>     mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer
>
> FocusIn event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
>     mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor
>
> KeymapNotify event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
>     keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
>            0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
> ```

- `<PrintScreen>` pressed and released again

> ```
> FocusOut event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
>     mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor
>
> FocusOut event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
>     mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer
>
> FocusIn event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
>     mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor
>
> KeymapNotify event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
>     keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
>            0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
> ```

- Sometimes when I press & release `<PrintScreen>`, the output shows a different `<serial>` altogether, such as (sharing just a snippet here):

> ```
> KeymapNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
>     keys:  4294967234 0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
>            0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
> ```

- `<Fn>` by itself returns nothing on `xev` unless coupled with some other (`f1` through `f12`) key. But even then it doesn't detect some

  - `Fn-f5` is supposed to be mapped to `XF86MonBrightnessDown` but returns nothing, similar for `Fn-f6` (`XF86MonBrightnessUp`). The xev raw output is similar to that of `<PrintScreen>`:

> ```
> FocusOut event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
>     mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor
>
> FocusOut event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
>     mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer
>
> FocusIn event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
>     mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor
>
> KeymapNotify event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
>     keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
>            0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
> ```

```
 * `Fn-f7` returns `NoSymbol` when it's supposed to be mapped to `XF86Display`
 * `Fn-f8` is mapped to `Super_L` somehow.
```

My questions are:

1. What do the weird output I have shared above mean and when are they returned?
2. What does the KeySym `NoSymbol` mean?
3. How do I correct wrong mappings--or generally--remap a key, such as the ones with `NoSymbol`

Hoping to build a concentrated, canonical reference to how keymappings generally work on UNIX-like systems through these questions that others with similar issues can refer to, so please be as detailed as time permits.

TIA!

Answer (score 3):

The `FocusIn` and `FocusOut` events mean some other application is reacting to the keypress. Usual suspects are your Window Manager ("WM", often part of "the Desktop") and other applications like assistants for language entry (Japanese, Chinese, etc.)

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> is usually intercepted by the [Embedded Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_controller) ("EC") of your laptop. It doesn't produce a normal key symbol, and the EC decides what to do with it, and what key events to generate when it is pressed together with other keys. This means you cannot customize it, because ECs for laptops are all different, and if they are configurable, the manufacturer keeps that secret.

`NoSymbol` means that whatever the EC returns for that key combination is not mapped to an X symbol. Use `evtest` to see what key events are produced in the kernel input layer.